# How to set two URL for single page in nextjs?

Tags: url, next.js, routes

```
http://localhost:3000/in/sports
http://localhost:3000/sports
```

The above two URLs lead to the sports page. but based on the country code the content of the page will be changed. If no country code is the default it will display the sports content from the US.

how can I create a page folder structure and redirect for it?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to implement this would be to use [next.js dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) in which your application will take the url argument and based on that display the content.

So your link will look like this "**localhost:3000/sports/*language_id***".

And your next.js folder structure will be like this: **pages/sports/[language_id].js**

Then in your **index.jsx** (inside sports folder) you will check language and display the content accordingly:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const SportPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { lang } = router.query;

  if (lang === "in") {
    return <IndianPage />
  } else {
    return <EnglishPage />
  }
}

export default SportPage;
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. 
But the country code should always be in the starting position of the URL.
And also I have some more URLs kind of the same structure on my site.

EX: 
Sports Page:
http://localhost:3001/us/sports
http://localhost:3001/sports

Genre page:
http://localhost:3001/us/concerts/pop
http://localhost:3001/concerts/pop

performer page:
http://localhost:3001/us/concerts/pop/elton-john
http://localhost:3001/concerts/pop/elton-john